# How to forward declare a template function in global or namespace with default argument?

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, forward-declaration, default-arguments

```
template<typename T> void foo (T t, int i = 0); // declaration

int main () { foo(1, 0); } // error!! 

template<typename T> void foo (T t, int i = 0) {} // definition
```

Above is a minimal reproducible example for a larger problem, where many header files are involved. Attempting to forward declare with default parameter results in below compilation:

> error: redeclaration of ‘template void foo(T, int)’ may not have default arguments [-fpermissive]

How to fix this?

Comment: `template<typename T> void foo (T t, int i) {} // definition`

Comment: You cannot use `=0` in the definition when forward declaring.

Comment: No need to provide default arguments for function defination.

Comment: You have placed // error!! on improper line!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A default argument, like `int i = 0`, is seen as a definition. Repeating it is therefore  an ODR-violation.

Don't know exactly why, except that the standard explicitly says so

> Each of the following is termed a *definable item*:
> [...]
> (1.6)   a default argument for a parameter (for a function in a given > scope)
> [...]
> No translation unit shall contain more than one definition of any definable item.

http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr

The solution is then to only have the default argument appear once, likely in the declaration (and not repeated in the definition).